# Powershell: Build table row groups by criteria for use in cycle

Tags: powershell, split

I am stuck on a problem within a larger processing chain. At a certain point I need to extract and build groups of table rows to replace values in some files. The input data looks like this:

```
element        level 
-------        -------
customer       9
quantity       1
language       2
system         3
writing        9
housing        1
society        2
recipe         3
entertainment  2
impression     1
theory         9
initiative     2
feedback       3
town           2
presence       3
```

The groups shall be build by the rows starting with and ending before level value "9" and every group shall be processed only once. So the first group I would like to hand over to a variable (e.g. $group) would be:

```
customer       9
quantity       1
language       2
system         3
```

Then I use the content in the overarching cycle. The second group that should replace the content in $group after that would be:

```
writing        9
housing        1
society        2
recipe         3
entertainment  2
impression     1
```

As you can see the number of items per group varies. Also the number of groups varies because the input data could also contain much more items and level 9 items.

My idea is to somehow foreach iterate through the rows after counting the sum of level 9 items to get the number of necessary repeats an to delete group by group (so that the loop starts at a new level 9 item with every cycle).

Any help very appreciated!
Daniel

EDIT
Here is the code of how I try to resolve it ($tmp contains the full data input as shown above):

```
        $lev9cnt = $tmp | ? Level -eq 9
        $lev9cnt.count
        $i = 1
        $group = @{}

        Foreach ($object in $tmp) {
    
            # check if cycle number is greater than number of level 9 items, stop repeating if yes
            if ($i -gt ($lev9cnt.count)) {
                $i++
                continue
            }
            
            # write level 9 hit to $group
            if ($object.Level -eq 9) {
            $group += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Element = $object.Element ; Level = $object.Level }
            }
             
            # write further items to $group
            if ($object.Level -lt 9) {
            $group += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Element = $object.Element ; Level = $object.Level }
            }
            
            # stop when coming to next level 9 and set counter +1
            if ($object.Level -eq 9) {
            $i++
            }

            write-host $group
            
        }
```

The error message is: FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddHashTableToNonHashTable but I am also not sure if the solution works anyway..

Comment: How is the order preserved ..?  or Can we say always the element name will be customer ?

Comment: Can you post the code on what you have tried, so we can help troubleshoot that? A hashtable seems like a reasonable solution here

Comment: @TheGameiswar No, the element strings vary ie "customer" is just an example (could be any other string)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala done, I have edited my question post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group the items like that, I would use two [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) objects.

```
# mockup table as array of PSCustomObjects
$table = @"
    element,level
    customer,9
    quantity,1
    language,2
    system,3
    writing,9
    housing,1
    society,2
    recipe,3
    entertainment,2
    impression,1
    theory,9
    initiative,2
    feedback,3
    town,2
    presence,3
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$subGroup = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$groups   = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

foreach ($item in $table) {
    if ($item.level -eq 9) {
        # if we have already built a subgroup, add it to the list
        if ($subGroup.Count) {
            # add the completed subgroup to the $groups list
            $groups.Add(($subGroup.ToArray()))
            # start a new subGroup
            $subGroup.Clear()
        }
    }
    $subGroup.Add($item)
}
# add the final subgroup to the list
if ($subGroup.Count) { $groups.Add(($subGroup.ToArray())) }
```

You now have a list of grouped PSCustomObjects

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $groups.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "Element $i" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $groups[$i] | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

```
Element 0

element  level
-------  -----
customer 9    
quantity 1    
language 2    
system   3    


Element 1

element       level
-------       -----
writing       9    
housing       1    
society       2    
recipe        3    
entertainment 2    
impression    1    


Element 2

element    level
-------    -----
theory     9    
initiative 2    
feedback   3    
town       2    
presence   3
```

Comment: tried it in my overall loop and works great (even tho I will have to dive into this in detail to understand it fully ;-) Thanks